# Defining a DB schema and having existing schema conform to it?

Tags: database, migration

I see a lot of DB migration tools that have up/down functions that deploy/revert DB schema changes. I have never seen a migration tool where you simply define the schema and it modifies your current DB schema to match the new definition.

Benefits:

- Simplicity, no need to manage a bunch of ups/downs
- Easily couple your schema with your code and keep both version controlled

Drawbacks:

- May drop data by removing columns; depends on how implementation deals with column removal

Am I really bad at Binging? Does this already exist? If not, what are the reasons? If it exists, is there a reason applications prefer an up/down model?

Comment: You appear to be asking why the ability to roll back changes to a database schema is considered valuable, which seems self-evident. Am I misreading your question?

Comment: @Ixrec I don't see much benefit in being able to roll back changes. Application logic is tightly coupled with DB schema. Why not just define the DB schema the version of code is supposed to work with, have something diff between the DB schema and the new schema, and apply necessary changes to match? It simplifies things by not needing to deal with ups/downs.

Comment: You can't find a DB migration tool that modifies any scheme to a specified one? That *is* weird. What else is such a tool supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a nice feature, and maybe there's a market for it if you write your own.

However, it is a very complex challenge.  For instance, if your target schema would rename a table or a column, the tool would take the new schema with new elements in it, find the existing schema, and compare both.  But how could it safely identify the renaming, and not confuse it with the drop of an obsolete column, and the creation of a new one ?    In some circumstances, it could make an educated guess (if the column is used in foreign keys or indexes).

So shortly said, this automation would work only for simple changes.  But for simple changes you don't really need an automatic tool.  And there is a high risk of destoying database by connecting to the wrong one.

Nevertheless the market is full of modeling tools, that can **reverse engineer** (*this is the term to goolgle*) an existing database to build a logical model, let you update the model and then generate update scripts ([oracle](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldevdm/r30/datamodel2moddm/datamodel2moddm.htm), [powerdesigner](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38058.1600/doc/html/rad1232021494242.html), etc...).  So not the full automation, but with some human wisdom in the process.

There is even this [dbshema](http://www.dbschema.com/features.html) tool which has a feature called schema [synchronisation](http://www.dbschema.com/database-schema-synchronization.html), which looks like what you are looking for, using the current schema to make transformation.  I haven't used it though, so I'll let you investigate further (and maybe share your conclusions here ?).